# How to tell if a ChildWindow is the 'top most' window

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

I'm working in Silverlight, but potentially a WPF solution would work as well.

My problem is very simple. I have lots of modal Child Windows that can be open, and in their generic menu is a home button. This button is supposed to close all of the child windows and return to the base screen. I have a few different types of 'generic child windows' that host lots of different UserControls, so by far the easiest way to implement this is to, when the window comes into focus, check if the global `ReturnToHome` bool is true, and if it is, just close it.

I've tried all of these

```
    private void ChildWindow_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (CommonResources.ReturnToHome) DialogResult = false;
    }

    private void ChildWindow_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (CommonResources.ReturnToHome) DialogResult = false;
    }

    private void ChildWindow_IsEnabledChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (CommonResources.ReturnToHome) DialogResult = false;
    }
```

The issue is, `GotFocus` doesn't fire until I actually click on the window. `MouseEnter` is a little better, but doesn't fire until I move the mouse. `IsEnabledChanged` never fires because the Child Window doesn't disable anything. Checking every child window when it closes to see if Home has been clicked isn't easy because of the sheer number of places where you can open child windows, and several of them are nested within User Controls where I couldn't even easily access `DialogResult`. Any idea how I could do this?

Also I should note that I want each of the windows to close one by one, from top down, because each window that closes does its own verification to see if it should warn the user before closing (giving the user the option to cancel closing)

Answer (score 0):

`TopMost` is a `bool` property which is either set to `true` or `false` and as far as I'm aware, there is no `public` property like `Z-Index` that will tell you the order in which your `Window`s were set to `TopMost`. However, there is a simple solution... just maintain a `static int` variable that will register this order. Each time you add a new `Window`, set the number into its `Tag` property:

```
Window childWindow = new Window();
childWindow.Tag = currentWindowNumber++;
...
childWindow.ShowDialog();
```

Then, when you want to close them in order, you can just do something like this:

```
foreach (Window window in Application.Current.Windows.OfType<YourWindowType>()
    .OrderBy(w => (int)w.Tag)) 
{
    ((AnimationWindow)window).CloseWindow();
}
```

Comment: I considered something like this, though there are a few problems with it. I can't just close them in order, I have to let each child window close itself, so it has the chance to let you cancel (say if that window has unsaved changes) and stop all those beneath it from being closed.

Comment: Whoops, posted too soon. I almost went with your order suggestion. I was trying to avoid that because some child windows get created, but they never get displayed because of some manner of error or whatever in loading. So there would need to be a fair amount of extra work in coding to check for that. I found a way to do it using the `VisualTreeHelper` to get a reference to the child window behind it, and call that window's close from the current window's Closed event handler.

Comment: Also, annoyingly, there's not `TopMost` in Silverlight